# Ionic app showing html code in simulator

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic-view

I just getting started with `Ionic` and have done environment setup for the same, but when I tried to emulate the app, below is happening:

1. Able to start the simulator
2. App also starts but it shows "html code" instead of app

Below are my files, I appreciate any help finding any mistakes.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Todo</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1,     user-scalable=no, width=device-width">

<link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
<script src=“js/app.js”></script>

</head>
<body ng-app="todo">
<ion-pane>
<ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
<h1 class="title">Awesome App</h1>
</ion-header-bar>
<ion-content class="padding">
<button class="button button-assertive">I'm a button</button>
</ion-content>
</ion-pane>
</body>
</html>
```

app.js
    angular.module(‘todo’, ['ionic’]);

[image: output on simulator is as follows :]

Comment: run "ionic serve -c " in cmd and see error there

Comment: It is just showing code in the browser same as it shows in simulator.. No error displayed as such .

Comment: error will be shown in command prompt OR you can inspect your browser

Comment: This is what i got on cmd prompt :

Running live reload server: http://localhost:35729
Watching: 0=www/**/*, 1=!www/lib/**/*
Running dev server:  http://localhost:8100
Ionic server commands, enter:
  restart or r to restart the client app from the root
  goto or g and a url to have the app navigate to the given url
  consolelogs or c to enable/disable console log output
  serverlogs or s to enable/disable server log output
  quit or q to shutdown the server and exit

ionic $

Comment: no errors can't help then

Comment: I appreciate any help finding any mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change quotation marks from `<script src=“js/app.js”></script>` to `<script src="js/app.js"></script>`

app.js should look like this

```
angular.module('todo', ['ionic'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {

      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);

      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
    }
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
})
```

And your app should look like this

[image]

Comment: Many thanks for your time and effort , will give it a try today :)

Comment: Changed quotation mark as suggested and updated app.js file as well , but still getting code in the output :( .

Comment: Are you using Windows or Mac? If you use a Mac have you tried with Xcode simulator?  Try to make a new project from scratch.

Comment: I am using Mac , Yes i have tried with XCode Simulator ..ok i will give it a try from scratch in Xcode once again . Thanks for suggestion .

Comment: Also, install ios-deploy `sudo npm install -g ios-deploy` if you want to install and debug iOS apps without using Xcode https://www.npmjs.com/package/ios-deploy.

Comment: @milankumar Are you in the meantime managed to solve the problem?

Comment: thanks for your time and support !! , i just got out of town and did not get time for the same . i will check it and update you . thanks again..

Comment: Trying with the fresh code and project is working .. thanks .. :)